# How to retrieve multiple set of values from db to a drop down in jsp page

Tags: java, html, oracle, jsp, web

I've tried with 'while loop'. but it displays only one row.
can someone tell me how to resolve the issue?

following is the code i've used :

```
<%    
 //oracle Connection.....
String a=select * from tblname where userid='"+userid+"' //with same     userid for  multiple records saved in db
Resultset rs=st.executeQuery(a);
while(rs.next)
{
%>
<li><option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>    //retrived only for single row
<%
}
%>
```

Comment: Could you please add your code here?

Comment: post your research / coding efforts

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a simple example. In this example I use [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html).

**Servlet:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    CustomerDao customerDao = new CustomerDao();

    List<Customer> customers = customerDao.getCustomers();

    request.setAttribute("customers", customers);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/customers.jsp").forward(request,
            response);

}
```

**JSP:**

```
<select>

    <c:forEach var="customer" items="${customers}">

        <option value="${customer.id}">${customer.name}</option>

    </c:forEach>

</select>
```

Comment: is there any way to get the values using jdbc connection ?

Comment: You should implement getting the data in DAO.

Answer (score 0):

For drop down you need to use `<select>` tag.Try like this:

```
 <%    
  //oracle Connection.....
  String a="select * from tblname where userid='"+userid+"'"; 
  Resultset rs=st.executeQuery(a);
  %><select><%
  while(rs.next())
  {
     %>
   <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>   
  <%
  }
  %>
  </select>
```

Also make sure that the query results in more than one row or else you will be getting one or may be no row.

Comment: Actually i've added the select tag but i missed it here :(

Comment: And i am only getting one row of value

Comment: If your query results in only one row then obviously you will be getting only one value in the dropdown.